# Can't scrape table using lxml

Tags: html, python-3.x, lxml, elementtree

I'm trying to scrape the urls for the individual players from this website.

I've already tried doing this with bs4 and it just returns [] every time i try to find the table. Switched to lxml to give this a try.

```
    import urlopen from urllib.requests
    import lxml.html

    url = "https://www.espn.com/soccer/team/squad/_/id/359/arsenal"

    tree = etree.HTML(urlopen(url).read())

    table = tree.xpath('/* 
 [@id="fittPageContainer"]/div[2]/div[5]/div[1]/div/article/div/section/div[5]/section/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/span')

    print(table)
```

I expect some sort output that I could use to get the links but the code returns square brackets

Comment: I think all data there is loaded through Javascript as JSON and then mapped to HTML tables through Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys


driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'C:\files\geckodriver.exe')
driver.set_page_load_timeout(30)

driver.get("https://www.espn.com/soccer/team/squad/_/id/359/arsenal")


continue_link = driver.find_element_by_tag_name('a')
elems = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@href]")
for elem in elems:
    print(elem.get_attribute("href"))
```